# How do you refer an instance of a model in model class in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, resque

I'm trying to refer an instance of User class in a Rails for geocoding

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  geocoded_by :address

  after_validation GeocodeJob.perform_later(self), if: :address_changed?
end
```

What I'm trying to pass on is the current instance of user. However as it is obvious, what I'm ending up passing is the class and not the instance, failing starting my job queue.

How can I refer and pass the user instance on a model callback? I know I can use instance variables using a controller, wondering if I can queue directly as a model callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With what you have currently written, `GeocodeJob.perform_later(self)` will be called when the class is loaded and it's return value will be used as the parameter passed to the call to `after_validation`.  As you say, that's not what you want.

Instead, you can pass a symbol for a method to call like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  geocoded_by :address

  after_validation :setup_geocode_job, if: :address_changed?

  def setup_gecode_job
    GeocodeJob.perform_later(self)
  end
end
```

This will do what you want by calling the instance method of the model and `self` will be the model instance.

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: Thanks @ihaztehcodez, that was spot on and nicely described. Regarding passing the id, my understanding was that since Rails 4.2 when we pass an instance, it is the global id and not the object that get passed. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @PunjCoder You are quite right.  It seems some confusing wording in sidekiq's github wiki had me confused about how rails 4.2 / ActiveJob handles passing instances.  Thanks for pointing that out, I will remove that bit from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely bad idea to use ActiveRecord instance directly as a job argument. The main problem here in serialization of Ruby object into some kind of a writeable format (JSON, YAML etc). Links to read more:

- Read comment from [ActiveJob source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7f18ea14c893cb5c9f04d4fda9661126758332b5/activejob/lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb#L17)
- The first point from [Sidekiq Best Practices](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-job-parameters-small-and-simple)

To access ActiveRecord instance in a job worker context it would be better to find the record by given id value:

```
class GeocodeJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def perform(user_id)
    user = User.find user_id
    # do hard geocode work here
  end
end
```

Start the job from callback like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  geocoded_by :address

  after_validation if: :address_changed? do |user|
    GeocodeJob.perform_later(user.id)
  end
end
```

**PS**. I would strongly recommend to use `after_commit` callback instead of `after_validation` because sometime record saving process might be cancelled in other callbacks or if some problem with database will be raised. One more thing here - if a user has not being saved before (like `User.create(...)`), its instance does not have id value.